# Enable Get File Contents

Tags: outlook-addin

This is my function:

```
Private Function Get_FileContents_FromWebpage(URL As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Get_FileContents_FromWebpage

    Dim objWeb As Object
    Set objWeb = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") ' Instantiate an instance of the web object

    With objWeb
        .Open "GET", URL, False ' Pass the URL to the web object, and send the request
        .send
        Get_FileContents_FromWebpage = .responsetext ' Look at the HTML string returned
    End With

    Set objWeb = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Get_FileContents_FromWebpage:
    Set objWeb = Nothing
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Function
```

I need assistance with enabling the following add on.

Add-Ins enable Get_FileContents

Comment: What is the question? Please provide more information.

Comment: 'Set tmpMDB = CurrentDb
Set tmpMDB = DAO.OpenDatabase(Range("dbpath").Value, False, True, "MS Access;PWD="")
Set rs = tmpMDB.OpenRecordset("Select DateVal from TBL where Par=''")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    dt = rs(0)
End If
rs.Close
'Summary
Sheets("Summy").Select
Range("L3") = FormatDate(Now())
Range("CEart").Select
rwn = ActiveCell.Row
Rows(rwn).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Rows(rwn + 1).Select
Selection.ClearContents
rwn1 = ActiveCell.Row
n = rwn
For i = 1 To rwn1 - rwn - 2
    Rows(rwn + 1).Select
    Selection.Delete next